# ActiveMQ seems to start but then I can't see it with netstat or ps

Tags: linux, activemq-classic

I start up ActiveMQ anid this is the output:

```
INFO: Loading '/etc/default/activemq'
INFO: Using java '/usr/bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties to get details
INFO: pidfile created : '/opt/activemq/data/activemq-localhost.pid' (pid '5282')
```

But then `netstat -a | grep 61616` returns nothing, and the pid that it named when it started is not included when I run the `ps` command. What could be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To debug startup failures is good to run the broker in foreground mode via:

```
./activemq console
```

This will cause errors to be logged on the console.  You can also check the logfile in the data folder in your activemq installation dir.

Comment: it output `ERROR: There are syntax errors in '/etc/default/activemq'` can I remove /etc/default/activemq and run setup again or is it better to try and fix it?

Comment: you could try moving it to activemq.old or something and then starting up.  Don't know what's in yours so can't say if its important or not.

Comment: I had stomp misspelled in my activemq.xml file. Haha Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I am getting like this: INFO: Loading '/usr/local/Cellar/activemq/5.11.2/libexec/bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties to get details
INFO: pidfile created : '/usr/local/Cellar/activemq/5.11.2/libexec/data/activemq.pid' (pid '87086')

Answer (score 0):

Two things that I use.

1) What Tim said in his answer.  Set your activemq instance to start in console mode via `activemq console`.  Other wise it will start logging to `/dev/null`  \

2) Crank yoru debug output level up so you can see more detail via `log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq=DEBUG`

Answer (score -1):

You should try to delete (or better rename to .old like suggested earlier) the /etc/default/activemq file. This fixed the problem for me.